# Why center widget won't work with rows and columns in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using rows and columns in my demo flutter app:

When I tried to add center widget to the column, it isn't working:

```
Center(
          child: Column(
            //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/bart.png"),
              ),
              Text(
                "Bart Simpson",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Pacifico",
                    fontSize: 40,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text(
                "FLUTTER DEVELOPER",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Source",
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    letterSpacing: 2.5,
                    color: Colors.teal.shade100),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
                width: 150,
                child: Divider(
                  height: 10,
                  color: Colors.teal.shade100,
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                elevation: 5,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 25),
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.phone,
                    color: Colors.teal,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    "+91 1234567890",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.teal.shade900,
                        fontFamily: "Source",
                        fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 10),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.email,
                      color: Colors.teal,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "bart@gmail.com",
                      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Source", fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        )),
```

I know that the property `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` would work but why isn't `Center` working?

From the docs it is stated that center will be as its child, then even if I state `widthFactor` and `heightFactor` it won't work.

In a youtube video I saw that `Center` would center its children according to its parent, then in my case parent of center is `SafeArea` widget then shouldn't it center it according to `SafeArea`'s width and height(nothing but the whole viewable screen)?

Comment: try to add these in your Column widget 
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

Comment: I have asked why center won't work. I know that this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center widget works as expected, but you're not able to see it because of your code.

Let's see how Center works:

### Center

> A widget that centers its child within itself.
>
> This widget will be as big as possible if its dimensions are
> constrained and widthFactor and heightFactor are null. **If a dimension
> is unconstrained and the corresponding size factor is null then the
> widget will match its child's size in that dimension.** If a size factor
> is non-null then the corresponding dimension of this widget will be
> the product of the child's dimension and the size factor. For example
> if widthFactor is 2.0 then the width of this widget will always be
> twice its child's width.

Center widget centers its child and in your case, the child is a Column which is set to `MainAxisSize.max`. That means your Column expanding as much as it can causes Center to match Column's size, leaving no space for Center to center its child in.

So, set mainAxisSize to `MainAxisSize.min` and then see results.